# parametrize solutions in null space of projection

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have $Pz = 0$ and $By = z$ for $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ invertible, $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ a projection. How can I parametrize the set $\{ y: PBy = 0 \}$?

Boyd's Convex [book (p.523)](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) gives a way to parametrize $\{ x : Ax = b \}$ for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}, n>p$, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in my case where I basically have $n=p$. Based on Boyd's method, I don't believe this would work (we'd only have one possible vector), so I'm wondering if there are any alternatives.